# Spawning objects after a period of time results in different outcome depending on time scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a part of my script. The GameObjects don't spawn at the time I expect them to. I tried to change the time scale in relationship to the delay value (i. e. timescale = 1 & baseDelay = .1f to timescale = 10 & baseDelay = 1). This how ever works like a charm and I really don't know why. Is something wrong with my code? Has unity problems with the FixedUpdate and small floats?

Images:

- http://i.epvpimg.com/hwgsbab.png
- http://i.epvpimg.com/WYBfbab.png

---

```
using System; using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour { 
internal int xCount = 5; //bricks in x per line 
internal float spacing = .5f; //space between bricks and margin to edges 
internal float baseDelay = .1f; //time that needs to pass until the next movement internal 
float brickMovementPerStep = .05f; //movement distance per step 
int currentLineNumber = 0; //index for current line

 void FixedUpdate()
 {
 //accurate value of space which needs to pass
 float dist = ((screenSize.x - (2 * spacing + ((xCount - 1) * spacing))) / xCount) * .667f + spacing;

 float stepsPerSecond = 1 / baseDelay; //how many steps are there per second?
 float movementPerSecond = stepsPerSecond * brickMovementPerStep; //how far will a line have moved?
 float requiredTime = dist / movementPerSecond; //how long will a line need to travel until the next one can be spawned?

 timeSinceLastSpawn += Time.deltaTime;
 if(timeSinceLastSpawn >= requiredTime)
 {
     timeSinceLastSpawn = 0; //reset time
     currentLineNumber++;
     SpawnAndStartLevel(); //this instantiates and moves the line, it is moved continously
 }
```

}

Comment: `FixedUpdate` should be used for Physics operation. You may want to use `Update` instead. If you still want to use `FixedUpdate`, then, use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` instead of `Time.deltaTime`

Answer (score 1):

`Time.deltaTime` is to be used in functions that update every frame. `FixedUpdate()` does not run every frame. `FixedUpdate()` is for physics - since you aren't doing any physics you should rename it to just `Update()`. I bet this will fix the anomalies in your timing. [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447682/what-is-the-difference-between-update-fixedupdate-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible that rounding errors occur. I'd recommend using a Coroutine with a `yield return WaitForSeconds(float)` for this, as you seem to do stuff in a fixed interval.

```
internal int xCount = 5; //bricks in x per line 
internal float spacing = .5f; //space between bricks and margin to edges 
internal float baseDelay = .1f; //time that needs to pass until the next movement internal 
float brickMovementPerStep = .05f; //movement distance per step 
int currentLineNumber = 0; //index for current line

bool run = true;
bool reset = false;

void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(LineRoutine(baseDelay));
}

public IEnumerator LineRoutine(float delay) {

    while (run){
        float dist = ((screenSize.x - (2 * spacing + ((xCount - 1) * spacing))) / xCount) * .667f + spacing;

        float stepsPerSecond = 1 / delay; //how many steps are there per second?
        float movementPerSecond = stepsPerSecond * brickMovementPerStep; //how far will a line have moved?
        float requiredTime = dist / movementPerSecond; //how long will a line need to travel until the next one can be spawned?
        while (!reset) {

            // stuff to happen every [requredTime] seconds
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(requiredTime);

            currentLineNumber++;
            SpawnAndStartLevel();
        }
        reset = false;
    }
}
```

btw it doesn't matter whether you use Time.deltaTime or Time.fixedDeltaTime in FixedUpdate, as stated in the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

Note that i don't recalculate the required time every iteration, as it seems to me that it won't be constantly changing. however if you set `reset` to true, it will leave that loop and recalculate the required time.

Comment: I changed the Time.* and FixedUpdate so it is uniform over all scripts in the project. After editing some code (especially deleting some obsolete stuff i did not include in the code above) it worked again. Thank you for taking your time though, I appreciate your help!