# The Update() function in my Unity build is only being called on certain objects while sending input in an unrelated script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I recently built my project and noticed a strange issue where certain objects, specifically those with simple rotation logic in their update functions do not execute unless I am sending input to the player.  To be more specific, I have a script attached to a fuel object (a collectable item) in my scene which handles collection of the fuel (via OnTriggerEnter) and sets a constant rotation for the object itself in the Update() function.

In editor everything works as expected, but in the most recent build the fuel object will only rotate while I am sending the thrust input to the player object (Rocket).

To further complicate things, it's only one object in the scene that behaves this way.  If there are three fuel objects, two of them behave normally while one rotates only during the thrust input.

In a different scene there is a large rotating obstacle in addition to several fuel objects.  In this scene the fuel objects all behave normally while the obstacle only rotates during thrust input.

This is the code that is behaving strangely.  I don't understand why my thrust input is having any impact on the update functions of objects that are rotating.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    //Set constant rotation
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed);
        
}
```

This is the Thrust function, though I don't believe that its an issue with the code.

```
void Thrust()
{
    if(state == State.Alive)
    {   
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) || InputManager.AButton())
        {
            childLight.enabled = true;
            fuelTotal--; 

            rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * primaryThrust * Time.deltaTime);
            if(!audioSource.isPlaying)
            {   
                if(submerged == false)
                {
                    audioSource.clip = thrustSound;
                    audioSource.Play();
                    thrustParti.Play();
                    thrusting = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    audioSource.clip = bubbles;
                    audioSource.Play();
                    bubbleParti.Play();
                    thrusting = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
            thrustParti.Stop();
            bubbleParti.Stop();
            childLight.enabled = false;
            thrusting = false;

            //ScaleMaskDown();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        childLight.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I haven't touched the scripts on these rotating objects or modified the thrust function in months.  Builds from several weeks ago do not have any of these issues present.  Has anyone run into this problem before.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to tell from here - this would mainly mean that your component doing the rotation is being disabled by something .... easiest way to find out is put some log there `private void OnDisable() { Debug.LogError("!!!!!!!! I have been disabled! :O How dare you!!!", this); }` .. and check the stack trace ... otherwise it would seem that something else is overruling the rotation - like e.g. Animation or another conflicting component ... to find out that you could use [`transform.hasChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this.  The fact that the unexpected behavior is migrating to a completely different (rotating) object from scene to scene is leading me to believe that it is not localized to a specific object.  I'll be back in town this weekend and will update.  Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34447723/10301322) answer can help you. At first glance it could be possible that, since `Update` gets called every displayed frame, there is a chance that `Update` is not called at all, as it is [explained in the forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/fixedupdate-fixed-framerate-frame-physics-step.250080/#post-1653139). Try to use `FixedUpdate` and see if it does solve your problem

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and got some really strange results. In the editor everything continues to work as expected when I change the Update function to FixedUpdate in the fuel script.  Once built, the entire game flickers constantly, The rotation function for the player script no longer works and the same rotation bug with the fuel object persists. I’m completely at a loss as these two scripts are not linked in any way. The fuel script only has a reference to the player (rocket) gameobject.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed ideas toward solving this issue.  I finally found a script attached to my canvas that was causing the issue.  I am still unsure why it created the problem as it references neither the fuel object nor the rocket object.  In any case, disabling this script has solved the problem.